# Work Assignment Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

We have a list of Workers and a list of tasks to be assigned to these workers. Each task is of a particular category, (around 50 categories for around 10000 tasks). Each worker can work on a set of categories, (around 5 categories for each worker). Also every worker has a maximum number of tasks which can be assigned to him.

We need to assign the tasks to the workers so that

a) maximum number of tasks can be assigned
b) No worker is assigned a task, which is outside the workers categories set
c) No worker is sitting idle, if there can be tasks assigned to him
d) Number of tasks assigned to any worker should be less than his maximum assignment

**Sample data:**

a) Tasks-category relation

```
T1 - C1
T2 - C1
T3 - C1
T4 - C2
T5 - C1
T6 - C3
..... (around 10k tasks, 50 categories)
```

b) Workers-Categories-Max number of tasks

```
W1 (100) - C1 
W1 (100) - C2 
W2 (20) - C1
W2 (20) - C3
..... (around 50 workers, each can work on around 5 categories). 
      Where 100 for W1 means W1 can be assigned maximum 100 tasks 
      (across all categories, it is mapped with).
```

I have tried looping through the workers and get their associated tasks and do their assignment one by one, but it has a loophole, that for some categories which have very few workers, the assignment is not fair, and some workers remain idle while some categories have tasks left, which can be assigned more efficiently by shuffling the tasks to some other workers.

For example, if C1 has 2000 tasks and three workers W1, W2, W3 with 1000 max tasks each. and C2 has 1000 tasks and is associated with W1 only. 
And if we assign C1 tasks to W1 and W2 to their full capacity (1000 tasks each), we cannot assign tasks of C2 as the associated worker W1 has been fully occupied with C1. Had we assigned C1 tasks to W2 and W3, we could have assigned all the tasks.

I need some algorithm which can efficiently and fairly do the assignment. If anyone has solved or knows about a possible solution/resource which I can use/explore, please suggest.

Comment: sounds like homework. give it a try on your own, if you encounter a specific problem, ask about it. no one is going to write your homework for you.

Comment: Agreed, it sounded like homework :), but the idea was to use an already tried and tested solution to the same or similar problem or just a pointer to a resource which I can explore (as suggested by blaze)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=maxFlow2

Example from "Maximum Bipartite Matching" is a classic "assign jobs to workers" task. You just need to link each worker only to tasks which are within its categories. Graph theory is your friend.